# Customize error messages in adp project - SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ms-access, adp

Hi I have a adp/SQL project running with my db. 
Everything is ok but is there a way to customize error messages.
Example: read user cannot update one field so he receives the standard SQL error msg. Is there a way to make it more user friendly?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using stored procedures, you can raise a custom error message, or you can have an output procedure that is returned with the error message.

If you're using direct sql syntax, then you can check the ADO error object and convert it to some sort of user defined error message.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Sum, I am interested in customized error messages, based on the input of the user